# Ldap authentication in symfony2

Tags: symfony, ldap

I'm trying to implement ldap authentication in Symfony2 and I'm stuck. All I want to do is to keep my users' data in database but check if theirs passwords are valid through ldap, so only users who have both the row in my users table and an ldap account have access to the application I'm working on.

I've read all the related docs (especially this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) and spend some time on reading the symfony code, but really have no idea how to do it. The security component looks very complex and I still don't understand how it works. Is there any way to switch just the Authentication Provider?

Comment: Maybe not the solution you are looking for but why not use a third party bundle: https://packagist.org/search/?q=ldap-bundle

Answer (score 1):

[FR3DLdapBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/fr3d/ldap-bundle) is perfect for your needs. It integrates with FOSUserBundle for user management against the DB and authentication against LDAP

Comment: This bundle is terrible to configure. I've been working with SF2 for quite a while now but this thing is a drama.